# Unable to add Rows dynamically to a Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, stackpanel

I want to add RowDefinitions to a Grid named notices. I could get the number of rows in the database and iterate those number of times, but I am unable to add the controls to a row.

The row is getting created, but StackPanel is not getting added. My code wants to create rows dynamically and to that a StackPanel and to the StackPanel a label and Image. In the .xaml file, I have only added the Grid.

How can I add a Row with StackPanel to the Grid?

This is my code:

```
    StackPanel sp;
    Label dt_label;
    Image img;
    BitmapImage bitmap;
    string col1=null,  col2 = "Picture_Path";
    string Picture_Path=null;
    RowDefinition gridRow1;
    DateTime time;

    for (int row_num = 0; row_num < No_Of_Rows; row_num++)
    { 
        DataRow row = dt1.Rows[row_num];
        foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();

            sp = new StackPanel();

            sp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            col1 = "Date_Time".ToString(); ;
            time = DateTime.Parse(dt1.Rows[row_num][col1].ToString());

            dt_label = new Label();
            dt_label.Content = time;

            Picture_Path = dt1.Rows[row_num][col2].ToString();

            img = new Image();

            bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(Picture_Path, UriKind.Relative);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            img.Source = bitmap;

            img.Height = 100;
            img.Width = 100;

            sp.Children.Add(dt_label); 
            sp.Children.Add(img);
            notices.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR \n" + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Delete all that code and use data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

You must set attached properties (`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`) to your controls using [Grid.SetRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc190424%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [Grid.SetColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.setcolumn).

After this you need to add control to grid like this:

```
nameOfYourGrid.Children.Add(nameOfYourControl);
```

Also, there are some *interesting* lines in your code:

```
"Date_Time".ToString(); ;
```

Why are you converting `string` to a `string`?

Majority of fields can be moved to inner `foreach` scope.